# Convolution with even function

Tags: integration, convolution

I want to demonstrate that the convolution $$(f \ast g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-\tau)g(\tau) \, d\tau$$ can be written in the form $$(f\ast g)(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}g(\tau)\left[f(x-\tau)+f(x+\tau)\right] \, d\tau$$

where $f$ is defined in $x>0$ but extended to $x<0$ by means of an even extension.

From what I can see the sensible place to start is to split the integral up as follows:

$$(f \ast g)(x)=\int_0^{\infty}f(x-\tau)g(\tau) \, d\tau +\int_{-\infty}^0f(x-\tau)g(\tau) \, d\tau$$ and then somehow use that $f(x)=f(-x)$ for $x<0$. How do I actually do this though?

Comment: Please do check your last line as it makes no sense. Did you mean $\;f(x)=f(-x)\;$ ? Is $\;f\;$ an even function?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, yes that is what I meant.

Comment: Fine, then also drop the "for$\;x<0$ ", as that must be true for **any** $\;x\;$ .

Comment: If $f$ is even, $f(x+\tau) \neq f(x-\tau)$ generally. It is true that $f(x+\tau) = f(-x-\tau)$.

Comment: The equality seems to be false unless for example $\;g\;$ is an even function...

Comment: Actually, it requires $g(\tau)=g(-\tau)$  (rather than $f(x)=f(-x)$)